# Decrement a field and delete entire object if field's value reaches to 0 in MongoDB & Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have array of objects like shopping list .for example i added 2 product to my list

```
cart:[{id:1,quantity:15},{id:2,quantity:5}]
```

i can increment and decrement quantities well  , but what i want to do is when i decrement to 0 i want it to show it as i dont have in my cart, i know its possible for pull and i tried this and fail.idk what i am doing wrong , when i try console.log(user) it gives me null ,because it doesnt see "cart.quantity":0 , idk why not. User info and layout is ok btw.

```
router.get("/:productId/decrement", auth, async (req, res) => {
  const user = await User.findOne({
    id: req.user._id,
    "cart.quantity": 0,
  });
  if (user) {
    await User.findOneAndUpdate(
      {
        id: req.user._id,
        "cart.id": req.params.productId,
        "cart.quantity": 0,
      },
      { $pull: { cart: { id: req.params.productId } } }
    );
  } else {
    await User.findOneAndUpdate(
      {
        id: req.user._id,
        "cart.id": req.params.productId,
      },
      { $inc: { "cart.$.quantity": -1 } },
      { new: true },
      (err, doc) => {
        if (err) {
          return res.json({ success: false, err });
        }
        return res.json({ success: true, cart: doc });
      }
    );
  }
});
```

and here is my user modal

```
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    maxlength: 50,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    unique: 1,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    minglength: 5,
  },
  lastname: {
    type: String,
    maxlength: 50,
  },
  cart: { type: Array, default: [] },
```

Comment: what is your MongoDB version ?

Comment: my version is 5.4.20

Comment: MongoDB version `4.2.x` is latest as of now ! I guess that's your driver version(You might be using mongoose, if I'm not wrong)(a driver helps to connect programming language code to database), I'm asking about MongoDB server version.. You can get it by doing `db.version()`.

Comment: yes youre right its mongoose,i downloaded mongoose via npm and didnt do anything about mongodb, just using application code from website to connect. should i install it as well?

Comment: When you say *website* is it mongo atlas ? If yes, then you can see MongoDB server version when you login to portal or atleast you can give above command in robo3T or shell (Once connected to DB) to get to know what version you're using..

Comment: Yes, i think its Version 4.2.6 , i see below the cluster.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215433/discussion-between-tolima-and-whoami).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**On MongoDB version >= 3.2 :**

```
router.get("/:productId/decrement", auth, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let bulkArr = [
      {
        updateOne: {
          filter: {
            id: req.user._id,
            "cart.id": req.params.productId,
            "cart.quantity": 1, // You can use {$lte : 1}
          },
          update: { $pull: { 'cart': { id: req.params.productId } } },
        },
      },
      {
        updateOne: {
          filter: {
            id: req.user._id,
            "cart.id": req.params.productId
          },
          update: { $inc: { "cart.$.quantity": -1 } },
        },
      },
    ];
    await User.bulkWrite(bulkArr);
    return res.json({ success: true });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error ::", error);
    return res.json({ success: false, ...{error} });
  }
});
```

**Note :**

1. I believe you're mixing `async-await`'s & `callbacks()`. Please try to avoid it.
2. In `bulkWrite` all filter conditions will be executed but update operation will only be executed if respective filter matches (kind of individual ops) but in one DB call.
3. `bulkWrite` outputs 'write result' but if you need result doc you need to do `.find()` call. But as the whole point of using `bulkWrite` is to avoid multiple calls to DB - If result has no errors you can send success message to front-end then they can show appropriate count (by doing decrement).

**Ref :** [.bulkwrite()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/index.html#db-collection-bulkwrite)

**On MongoDB version >= 4.2 :**

As we can use aggregation in updates you can do like below :

```
User.findOneAndUpdate({id: req.user._id, 'cart.id': req.params.productId},
   [
    {
      $addFields: {
        cart: {
          $reduce: {
            input: "$cart",
            initialValue: [],
            in: {
              $cond: [
                { $and: [ { $eq: [ "$$this.id", req.params.productId ] }, { $gt: [ "$$this.quantity", 1 ] } ] }, // condition
                {
                  $concatArrays: [ "$$value", [ { $mergeObjects: [ "$$this", { quantity: { $add: [ "$$this.quantity", -1 ] } } ] } ]]
                }, // condition is true, So we're decrementing & pushing object to accumulator array
                {
                  $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$$this.id", req.params.productId ] }, "$$value", { $concatArrays: [ "$$value", [ "$$this" ] ] } ]
                } // condition failed, so pushing objects where id != input productId
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ], {new: true})
```

**Ref :** [aggregation-pipeline-for-updates](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/index.html#use-an-aggregation-pipeline-for-updates), [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/index.html#reduce-aggregation)

Test aggregation pipeline here : [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZI7r20yGOfr)

**Note :**

Few MongoDB clients may throw an error saying 'update operations may only contain atomic operators' that case you can use `.update()` or testing it using code as most drivers that support `4.2` doesn't throw such errors.

Comment: Thank you i tried 4.2 and it works like a charm but i still dont know why mine didnt, especially User.findOne({
    id: req.user._id,
    "cart.quantity": 0,
  });

Comment: @Tolima : Not sure, Is `id: req.user._id` unique ? Also are you sure that when you've used your query did any matching doc exists in collection or not ?

Comment: yes its unique, it gives me null , i expected it to match after i decrement quantity till 0

Comment: @Tolima : Try to execute query directly on DB & check result, What is type of `id` field in MongoDB document ? Check if input types match with types of fields in document (You usually don't get any doc if there is a type mismatch, eventually `.findOne` will return `null`)

Comment: query works well when i post increment request, but i also noticed that when i decrement or increment it doesnt go 1 by 1 it is another problem and your code also fixes it ,so i decided to not focus on my old one and i must learn about $reduce part ,it seems tough

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Create a partial index that only indexes documents where the field value equals or is less than 0 (depending on your needs)
2. Add a TTL to "expire after 0 seconds" on a field that is set to 0. (i.e. all indexed documents are set to expire immediately).

On Java it would look like:

```
new IndexModel(
    Indexes.ascending(ZERO_FIELD),
    new IndexOptions().expireAfter(0L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .partialFilterExpression(Filters.lte(VALUE_FIELD, 0)
    )
)
```